# Finding extreme values when the determinant of the Hessian at a critical point is zero.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We want to determine extreme values of $f(x,y)=x^3+xy^2-x^2y-y^3$.
We first determine critical points by solving $\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=0$ and 
$\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$ which gives that the only critical point is $(0,0)$.
Now we compute the determinant of the Hessian $$D(x,y)=(6x-2y)(2x-6y)-(2y-2x)^2$$
Hence $D(0,0)=0$ and the determinant of the Hessian test is not conclusive, so what to do next to verify existence of local and global extreme values? thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

A hint:

You can factor your function and decide what's happening at $(0,0)$ by inspection.

Comment: Can we say that $f(1/n,0)=1/n^3>0$ while $f(0,1/n)=-1/n^3<0$ hence the point $(0,0)$ can't be an extreme value?

Comment: @palio: That's it.

Answer (score 2):

When your Hessian determinant is equal to zero, the second partial derivative test is indeterminant. So then you could simply look at the equation or you can develop contours around possible mins and maxs and use Gauss's Theorem to see if there are mins and maxs within them. So essentially, if the Hessian is equal to zero, you are screwed or the question is really easy and you can find the answer by inspection.